# What is the most effective way to pass dela riva spider?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu

It's a particularly frustrating guard for me to start passing and often if I even get close then the transition to single leg x happens.

I have seen a few tutorials of Mendes brothers, etc., using a leg drag on the bicep control but this is actually quite difficult to achieve in my experience.

Some YouTube videos for reference:

- [De la riva spider leg drag pass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_vjAIhqWSk)
- [De la riva spider knee bump to leg weave](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3LtZzKwSKI)
- [Mendes brothers de la riva pass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-Ook1kchPI)

Comment: Could you add links to explain what 'dela river spider' is and to the tutorials you've seen?

Comment: Links added to original post for clarity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What drills are good to escape/break Spider Guard?](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/what-drills-are-good-to-escape-break-spider-guard)

Comment: Im not really looking for a drill to pass normal spider guard, I can back away and move to the side to pass this, step on the leg to pin it etc. I am specifically looking to pass dlr spider with a ankle\pant grip on the drl side and killing the entry to single leg x\anaconda guard. Also I am looking for tried and personally tested techniques against good level opponents purple and above with a link to a video possibly if they have one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a BJJ coach and run bjjtech.com and covered this question over there. Here it is:

**Setup: The Initial Situation**
You are standing inside his de la riva guard. He is setting up any variation of the De la Riva guard where his leg is wrapped around your lead leg. This might include him also gripping your sleeve and applying pressure to your rear leg with his other foot. Much of this technique applies to gi only, but can be adapted for no-gi. In this example, his left leg is wrapped around your right lead leg.

**Steps**

1. Grab the end of his left pant leg with your left hand. You will be reaching slightly under your right thigh to reach this.
2. Quickly turn your hips, pivoting on your right foot, spinning your left leg behind you. While you are turning your back to him, you will maintain control of his right leg and land tight around his left thigh.
3. Immediately and strongly clamp your left thigh on his left leg above his knee. Your right foot should be planted inside his left thigh and should be touching your left thigh. This will ensure you are as tight as possible.
4. Grab his belt or the top of his pants with your right hand. This will maintain control of him as you kneebar him and will help prevent him from improving position momentarily.
5. Lie to your left and extend the kneebar

**More detail**
Here's [a link to the full technique on bjjtech.com](http://www.bjjtech.com/tech/358).
And [a link to the embedded YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qrdL2CPyuw).

Comment: This is good pass, I have not seen the back step to knee bar before, just clamping the head. I will give it a go, the problem is still that spider guard bicep control though because I cant back step if they have that. Do you have a drill\ tech video for killing the entry to single leg x as when I start to free the bicep control a lof the time they step on the mat and kick into single leg x.

Comment: Good question, @berimbolo. I think the single leg x is defeated quickly by addressing it directly. As in the full X, attack the foot. The single butterfly hook behind the knee (the single leg x) should be gripped just above the big toe knuckle at the end of his foot (across the entire foot for a good grip). Even the threat of a footlock will "change the subject" quick enough for you to buy time for spinning to the kneebar. Regarding the spider biceps control, check out my technique here: http://www.bjjtech.com/tech/316. I found this by going to http://bjjtech.com and searching for "spider". :)